# $\lim_{x\to 3} \frac{x^3-27}{\sqrt{x-3}}$

Tags: calculus

I was trying to calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 3} \frac{x^3-27}{\sqrt{x-3}}$$

and, feeding it into WolframAlpha, I found the limit is $0$.

But;  the function isn't defined  from the left of $3$

My knowledge is that the function must be defined  in an  open interval  around $\{ x_0\}$ ; "neighbourhood"

So, is the answer of WolframAlpha correct,  or does the limit not exist?

Comment: Make it $\lim_{x\to3^+}\cdots$ and take anything that Wolfie A tells you with a grain of salt.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: no, Wolfram is perfectly right, as usual. As the domain is limited to the positive $x-3$, the limit to $3$ is implictly the limit to $3^+$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I noticed that the limit to $3^-$ according to Wolfram is $0$

Comment: @LorenzoBergamaschi: right. Wolfram considers complex arguments by default so that here all limits are defined and coincide. I couldn't find a way to enforce a real argument but if the limit exists in the complex, it exists in the reals a fortiori. When you try $e^{1/x}$ to zero, Alpha kindly details the three limits.

Answer (score 5):

If a limit point is at the boundary of a domain, an open neighborhood may not contain points on all sides. For example, in the relative topology of $[3,\infty)$, $[3,4)$ is an open set, and the limit as $x\to3$ is a one-sided limit. Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to3}\frac{x^3-27}{\sqrt{x-3}}
&=\lim_{x\to3^+}\frac{x^3-27}{\sqrt{x-3}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to3^+}\sqrt{x-3}(x^2+3x+9)\\[3pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The limit does exist (as a rule of thumb, Wolfram is more often right than humans are).

In the definition of a limit, you only consider the part of the open interval *that belongs to the domain* (here $\mathbb R^+$). As you can check on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit#Precise_statement_for_real_valued_functions), $x\in D$ is required.

If that rule was not enforced, you would never have a limit at an endpoint nor in more complicated situations (think of $x\sqrt{\sin(1/x)}$), which would make it a poorer concept.

---

As an alternative way to compute this limit, you can shift the argument and write

$$
\lim_{x\to 3} \frac{x^3-27}{\sqrt{x-3}}=\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{(y+3)^3-27}{\sqrt{y}}=\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{y^3+9y^2+27y}{\sqrt{y}}=\lim_{y\to 0} (y^2+9y+27){\sqrt{y}}.
$$

---

**Update**:

By default Wolfram works in the complex. As the function is defined for all $z\ne0$, there is no domain limitation and Alpha does not answer the very question (though it does it implicitly by not raising a discussion on the sign).

Comment: so what do you think is the right answer?

Comment: @prayersmith: my answer says it very clearly, read again.

Answer (score 1):

First, note $x$ must be not less than $3$ for a root to be defined, and greater than $3$ for a denominator to be nonzero (hence a function defined). So any 'open interval' you may consider *must* be a subset of the domain, which is, at most, $(3,\infty)$.

Then:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{x^3-27}{\sqrt{x-3}} & = \frac{(x-3)(x^2+3x+9)}{\sqrt{x-3}} \\
& = \frac{\sqrt{x-3}\,\sqrt{x-3}\,(x^2+3x+9)}{\sqrt{x-3}} \\
& = \frac{\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x-3}}\cdot\sqrt{x-3}\,(x^2+3x+9) \\
& = \sqrt{x-3}\,(x^2+3x+9)
\end{align}$$

Now the existence of a limit is quite obvious, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: we have $$x^3-27=(x-3)(x^2+3x+9)$$

Comment: is the answer $0$ or doesn't exist

Comment: I agree with @prayersmith. If the function is defined from Real numbers to Real numbers, then it is not defined for x < 3. Therefore in real numbers, the left hand limit does not exits and hence the limit will not exist.

Comment: Can't we see that the limit tends to zero if we apply L'Hospital's rule? so differentiate the numerator and denominator with respect to $x$ and let $x \rightarrow 3$ to get the desired result?

Comment: I don't think that this hint addresses the question asked (or was the question updated ?)

Comment: @Yves Daoust  no , the question wasn't updated